# RHEL NFS boot error

Tags: boot, nfs, pxe

I have battled for two days attempting to get a basic NFS root install to boot up. I am working with RHEL 6.6 and after following both the RHEL tutorial (Section 24 in the manual) and another internet tutorial (found [here](https://rags.wordpress.com/2012/03/20/using-nfsroot-to-boot-diskless-clients-on-rhel/)), I still have not been able to get the system to boot.
I used dracut to generate the .img and initramfs from a local RHEL 6.6 install.

The PXE is ok; an address is requested and the image is found and opened. Near the end of starting up, an error is thrown:

```
dracut: FATAL: Don't know how to handle 'root=nfs:192.9.220.1:/export/home/spice/root/'
```

I have played with the `/tftpboot/pxeboot.cfg/default` and am currently using the following settings (although I have tried altering it many times):

```
default HELiOS6.6
 label HELiOS6.6
   kernel vmlinuz-2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64
   append initrd=initramfs.img root=nfs:192.9.220.1:/export/home/spice/root/
```

The 192.9.220.1 is the host PC (running the DHCP, PXE, etc...)

I also have been monitoring `/var/log/messages` on the host system and there are no errors showing up there. The only info I am getting is from the dhcpd service that it is handing out an IP (the correct one). Also I have verified I can mount the NFS share from across the network just fine.

Here's a photograph of the boot screen, showing the error transcribed above:
[image: photograph of the boot screen]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Try using `nfsroot=192.9.220.1:/export/home/spice/root/` instead of `root=`.

Comment: install dracut-network and remake your initramfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution was to use dracut with the appropriate networking flags. RHEL6's tutorial did not include these flags when talking about nfs root, that is why I did not know about them. In summary of the key steps done to perform a root nfs install with RHEL6 follows:

```
#Install dracut-network on RHEL6 (The Host Machine)
 yum install dracut-network –y
#Do a remote root install to the export directory where to nfs root will live.
 yum groupinstall Base --installroot=/export/home/spice/root –y
#Use darcut with nfs flags to 
 dracut -d nfs -d network -f
#Also had to turn off kdump to avoid errors.
 chroot  /export/home/spice/root  chkconfig kdump off
```

Thanks guys.